# How to execute Symlink command in java

Tags: java, command, symlink

I am finding trouble in executing symlink command in java. My source filename and destination filename has space in it. 
How to execute this command?

Eg. ln -sf /home/Desktop/image1 .jpg /home/Desktop/Folder/image 2.jpg

I am trying this code

```
    String command = "ln -sf " + "/home/Desktop/\"image 1.jpg\"" + " /home/Desktop/Folder/\"image 2.jpg\"";
    CommandLine oCmdLine = CommandLine.parse(command);
    DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
    oDefaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
    try {
        oDefaultExecutor.execute(oCmdLine);
    } catch (ExecuteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easy with NIO.2

```
Path directoryTarget = Paths.get("c:/temp");
Path directoryLink = Paths.get("c:/links/linkTemp");

Files.exists(directoryTarget);

try {
  Files.createSymbolicLink(directoryLink, directoryTarget);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying same. Before creating link, I need to delete existing link right? using Files.delete(directoryTarget);

Comment: Yes, before you create the link, delete possible existing link with Files.deleteIfExists(fileLink1);